# How to check any property of State has any null value or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the state of my App:

```
 const [state, setState] = useState({
    priceType: 0,
    recurrenceType: 0,
    start_date: '',
    end_date: '',
    minCapacity: 0,
    maxCapacity: 0,
    price: 0,
    min: 0,
    max: 0,
    days: []
});
```

Here is the code of condition in which I am trying to achive, if any property of the state has null value then return true otherwise return false.

```
const isNullish = Object.values(state).every(value => {
        if (value==='' && value===0 && value === []) {
          return true;
        }
        return false;
      });
console.log(isNullish)
console.log(state)
```

But the chalenge is whenever I execute that code in my app it returns false although the properties has no value.Below is the console output of above code:

```
false
SpecialPrice.jsx:124 {priceType: 0, recurrenceType: 0, start_date: '', end_date: '', 
minCapacity: 0, …}
days: []
end_date: ""
max: 0maxCapacity: 0
min: 0
minCapacity: 0
price: 0
priceType: 0
recurrenceType: 0
start_date: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
SpecialPrice.jsx:129 []
```

For better understanding I have attached a screenshot here:

[image]

Comment: read about truthy and falsy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First problem:

The logic is asserting a value is equal to three different other values with the logical AND (`&&`), which will just about *always* be false.

```
value === '' && value === 0 && value === []
```

A value can never be strictly equal to a string `''` ***and*** a number `0`, ***and*** an empty array `[]`.

You *could* assert on the inverse of each though, checking for inequality.

```
value !== '' && value !== 0 && value !== []
```

Second problem:

The last condition, `value === []`, even if `value` currently had the value `[]`, `[] === []` *always* evaluates false, they are two object references and these can never be strictly equal.

```js
const value = [];
console.log(value === []); // false
console.log([] === []);    // false
```

## Solution

Use logical OR (`||`) instead to check each condition.

The final condition should first check if the value ***is*** an array and then check for 0 length, or use the Optional Chaining operator (*basically to guard against undefined `value` values*).

Example:

```
const isNullish = Object.values(state).every((value) => {
  return value === "" || value === 0 || (Array.isArray(value) && !value.length);
});
```

or

```
const isNullish = Object.values(state).every((value) => {
  return value === "" || value === 0 || !value?.length;
});
```

or since both `''` and `0` are considered [falsey values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) you can further simplify the conditionals.

```
const isNullish = Object.values(state).every((value) => {
  return !value || !value.length;
});
```

Falsey values include `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `""` (*and other empty strings*), `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`.

```js
const state = {
  priceType: 0,
  recurrenceType: 0,
  start_date: "",
  end_date: "",
  minCapacity: 0,
  maxCapacity: 0,
  price: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  days: [],
  days2: undefined
};

const state2 = {
  priceType: 0,
  recurrenceType: 0,
  start_date: "",
  end_date: "",
  minCapacity: 0,
  maxCapacity: 0,
  price: 0,
  min: 0,
  max: 0,
  days: [3],
  days2: undefined
};

const isNullish = arr => Object.values(arr).every((value) => {
  return !value || !value.length;
});

console.log(isNullish(state));  // true
console.log(isNullish(state2)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

`.every` is in this case not the right approach. With .every you check if every value is 0 or []. In your case not every value is 0 or [].

I would suggest you use `.some`

Something like this:

```
const isNullish = Object.values(state).some(x => x === 0 || x === [] || x === '');
```

Comment: Just FYI, using `.every` fails early just like `.some` completes early when the predicate function hits the correct condition. In other words, as soon as `.every` hits a returned falsey value from the callback it stops and returns false, it won't keep looking for truthy values since it already knows not every value passes the condition. If you want to use `.some` though you should invert all the conditions, looking for *some* value that *isn't* "nullish", and if you find one, return false. With `.every` we're asserting all *are* "nullish" and return false if we find one that isn't.